# Calling PHP Function inside TD tag

Tags: php, function, html-table

I have a little problem..

```
"<td height=50>" . captcha() . "</td>";
```

^ The above code is a long code and that's just a little part of it, well everything seems to work fine. However, the only problem is that the captcha (image, which is called by the function) is not in the TD tag, it is completely outside the table..

Anyway to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: than why don't you echo it outside the table simply? give us the compete code

Comment: You should probably inspect the generated HTML aswell.

Comment: what does captcha() return? you need to give more information. Nobody understand what it is you use. If it returns a url to your image, then make sure you wrap it inside a IMG tag. <img src="<%=captcha()%>">

Comment: More Information would be required ...

Comment: Probably the `captcha()` function returns another `<td><img /></td>` structure which is not allowed within HTML.

Comment: the captcha() functions returns a div tag with dots (images) in it.

Comment: The captcha function returns nothing. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the function doesn't return a value, but instead it echoes it:

```
function b() {
  echo "b";
}

echo "a" . b() . "c";
```

In this code example, you will see that it outputs `bac`. The reason being, that `b` is already echoed, while the string 'a' . `void` . 'c' (resulting in `ac`) is being put together.

Undoubtedly, your captcha function has the same problem.

Solution: Use `return` instead of `echo` in your function.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to concatenate the `captcha` function inside the `td`? You say this is part of more code, could you try something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td><?php echo captcha(); ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```